# MariaDB optimal configuration on CentOS

Tags: centos, centos7, mariadb

I have a cloud server with the following config:

```
CPU:8 vCore (4 Core, 4 Processor)
RAM:16 GB
SSD:240 GB
```

This server features CentOS7-64bit with MariaDB running as the database. (Date bug is fixed)

The server is very database intensive and updated near constantly.

I am seeing > 95% utilization on the server but I believe the default configuration is more to blame then running out of resources.

I'd like to offload more of the work to the RAM which is only 11% used by MySQL/MariaDB.

```
41724 mysql     20   0 10.163g 1.765g   9704 S 298.0 11.3  19:10.43 mysqld
```

[Using this Serverfault questions I've adjusted my Database config file as best I could](https://serverfault.com/questions/686665/mysql-showing-100-cpu-usage).

This has improved some but is there anything else I can do to improve the performance outside of upgrading CPU?

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = ::
skip_name_resolve
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=4G
max_allowed_packet=128M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 100M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 784M
tmp_table_size= 2048M
max_heap_table_size= 2048M
skip-name-resolve
innodb_buffer_pool_size= 7G
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

Comment: Please post the output of `top`, `iostat -x -k -n 60` and `sar` (for the latest two programs, you need to install the `sysstat` package)

Comment: What is wrong with > 75% (CPU) utilization? You want your server to utilize the CPU / execute queries. Is there an actual problem?

Comment: Typo @HTTP500, I meant 95%

Answer (score 0):

Also you could tune this parameters:

```
thread_concurrency              = 65
read_buffer_size                = 524288
thread_cache_size               = 16
join_buffer_size                = 12M
tmpdir                          = /tmp(it should be on tmpfs)
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 25M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll monitor top and see if this has an affect.  Any parameters that can offload the CPU load to RAM you can suggest?  Currently 11% is in use by MySQL/MariaDB even though I've allocated innodb_buffer_pool_size= 7G

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco what size your databases? They can't take more then they use on disk.